# Find the directional derivative of the function $\phi=x^2-y^2+2$ at the point $P(1,2,3)$ .

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**Question:** Find the directional derivative of the function $\phi=x^2-y^2+2$ at the point $P(1,2,3)$ in the direction of the st.line $PQ$, where $Q$ is the point $(5,0,4)$.

$\dfrac{d\phi}{ds}=(l\hat{i}+m\hat{j}+n\hat{k})\cdot \left( \dfrac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x}\hat{i}+ \dfrac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial y}\hat{j}+ \dfrac{\partial \phi_3}{\partial z}\hat{k}\right)=(\dfrac{4}{21}\hat{i}+\dfrac{-2}{21}\hat{j}+\dfrac{1}{21}\hat{k})\cdot (2x\hat{i}+-2y\hat{j})=\dfrac{4(2x+y)}{21}\implies \left[ \dfrac{d\phi}{ds}\right]_Q=\dfrac{4(10+0+y)}{21}=\dfrac{40}{21}$.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\overrightarrow {PQ}=(4,-2,1)$

I think it is easy to use this definition of the directional derivative.

$\nabla_v \phi(x)=\lim \limits_{h \to0}\frac{\phi (x+h v)-\phi (x)}{h}$

so, if $u=\frac{PQ}{|PQ|}$

$\nabla_u \phi(P)=\lim \limits_{h \to0}\frac{\phi (P+h u)-\phi (P)}{h}
=\lim \limits_{h \to0}\frac{\phi (1+4h/\sqrt{21},2-2h/\sqrt{21},3+h/\sqrt{21})-\phi (1,2,3)}{h}$

$
\nabla_u \phi(P)=\lim \limits_{h \to0}\frac{(1+4h/\sqrt{21})^2-(2-2h/\sqrt{21})^2+2-(1^2-2^2+2)}{h}$
$=\lim \limits_{h \to0}\frac{16h/\sqrt{21}+12h^2/21}{h}=\frac{16}{\sqrt{21}}$